# How many 10 digit numbers begin with (652)- and contain no zeroes?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I'm slightly confused, but I answered it as $9^7$.

My reasoning is that the area code isn't relevant to how many numbers are possible, which leaves it as $7$ digits with $9$ possibilities each (since $0$ can't be used)

So the answer should be $9\times9\times9\times9\times9\times9\times9$ (one $9$ for each digit that needs a number between $1$-$9$) or $9^7$, right?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. In the future please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format numbers and and math expressions.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I appreciate it. Sorry my post wasn't formatted properly, I'll be sure to have my next post be up to Mathjax standards.

Comment: On a related note (albeit probably irrelevant to your question), 10-digit numbers in the US used to be rather more restricted than they appear: the area code always had a 0 or 1 as the middle digit, and the first and 3rd digits were neither 0 nor 1. The next three digits (the "exchange") were made up of the digits 2...9. The last four digits usually did not start with a 9, which was reserved (at least in some areas) for public-telephone numbers. The original plan was that this scheme would serve until the year 2000; I've heard that that estimate was ruined by the advent of fax machines.